# JavaMail - Pop3Folder accidentally gets closed

Tags: glassfish, jakarta-mail

After successfully opening `Pop3Folder`, and retrieving messages from it, I then sometimes get to the point, when `folder.isOpen` returns `false`. At the same time, when looking at the `Pop3Folder`'s fields in debug mode, I see that the field `opened` set to `true`.

Could somebody give me a hint, what might go wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
public void popMail(MessageProcessor messageProcessor) throws MessagingException {
  Folder inboxFolder = null;
  Store store = null;
  try {
    store = mailSession.getStore();
    store.connect(mailSession.getProperty("mail.user"),
        mailSession.getProperty("mail.password"));
    // OK. Connected to POP3 Store.
    inboxFolder = store.getFolder("inbox");
    inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    // The folder is successfully opened.
    Message[] msgs = inboxFolder.getMessages();
    // Messages are successfully retrieved.
    if (msgs != null && msgs.length > 0) {
      for (Message msg : msgs) {
        if (messageProcessor != null) {
          // Calling custom listener to process message
          messageProcessor.processMessage(msg);
        }
        msg.setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);
      }
    }
  } finally {
    // Oops, inboxFolder.isOpen returns false.
    // Meanwhile I see in debug mode that inboxFolder#opened is set to true
    if (inboxFolder != null && inboxFolder.isOpen()) {
      try {
        inboxFolder.close(true);
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.warn("Error while closing folder");
      }
    } if (store != null) {
        try {
          store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
          log.warn("Error while closing store");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may be timing out the connection if your processMessage method takes too long.  Turn on Session debugging and examine the protocol trace for clues.

Comment: I didn't turn the debugging on, but I can say for sure that after about 2 minutes of processing messages the folder eventually gets closed. So yes, it's most likely the server timing out connection. Thanks again!